# Variable seen as System.EventArg which seems to be KeyPressEventArg

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

```
Private Sub RichTextView_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
   KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextView.KeyPress, RichTextView.TextChanged

    Dim c As Char = e.KeyChar
    Dim i As Integer = Asc(c)
    Dim h As Char = Chr(i)

capitalise_first_letter.Add(h)
End Sub
```

The above code produces the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs'.`  It throws the error at `capitalise_first_letter.Add(h)` (capitalise_first_letter is a List of String).

Why? Since h is e.KeyChar put through transformations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're also trying to use the same routine to handle `RichTextView.TextChanged`, which does not pass `KeyPressEventArg`.

You need a separate event handler for the `TextChanged` event if you want to allow this to be `KeyPressEventArgs`.